# How to create bitbucket repo using terraform

Tags: bitbucket, terraform

I am trying to create a bitbucket repo using terraform using example provided here : https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/bitbucket/index.html .
To make it simple, I hardcoded all values like username,pass,repo name etc...
I am able to run terraform plan which says 1 resource to create but when i apply the plan it throws error :

```
Error applying plan:
2017/04/03 16:54:26 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for all plugin processes to complete...
1 error(s) occurred:
bitbucket_repository.bbrepo: 1 error(s) occurred:
bitbucket_repository.bbrepo: EOF
2017/04/03 16:54:26 [DEBUG] plugin: terraform: bitbucket-provider (internal) 2017/04/03 16:54:26 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for all plugin processes to complete...
```

tf file:

```
# Configure the Bitbucket Provider
provider "bitbucket" {
  username = "<BITBUCKET LOGIN EMAIL>"
  password = "<BITBUCKET PASSWORD>"
}


# Manage your repository
resource "bitbucket_repository" "bbrepo" {
  owner = "<OWNER USER ID>"
  name  = "<REPO NAME TO CREATE>"
}
```

Also how to provide bitbucket url if I have internal hosted bitbucket ?
Terraform version - 0.9.2

Thanks

Comment: The bitbucket provider currently only works for Bitbucket in the Cloud rather than Bitbucket server although the docs don't make that too clear. I'm guessing that's your issue and it's just not giving a helpful error message if your credentials aren't valid on bitbucket.org ?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I also tried this example against bitbucket in cloud (i.e bitbucket.org) and gave same error.
I am sure my credentials are okay as I am able to login to bitbucket.org using those credentials and able to run terraforim import bitbucket_repository command to import state of existing repo on terraform.

Answer (score 1):

The bitbucket provider embedded in terraform only supports bitbucket cloud.

For self-hosted (aka bitbucket server), I have a community provider available to handle exactly these types of use cases: https://gavinbunney.github.io/terraform-provider-bitbucketserver